# Stack Overflow App Black Theme

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-app

Can we have a black theme for the Stack Overflow Application?

Comment: I never cease to shock over the fact that a code driven website don't have a dark theme

Comment: At least it arrived, just took them 12 years. Now let's way another 12 for meta to become dark as well.

Answer (score -9):

Sure:

https://userstyles.org/styles/35345/stackoverflow-dark